# how to clear spinner value in android

Tags: android, spinner

i have two spinners when i select items(other then first item) in first spinner which is saved in array it populates data in spinner second which comes from web services. i want that when i again select first data which is title of spinner first it should clear all the value from spinner second. i did all tricks but helpless. suggest me.

my code is:

```
  if(spinner1== 0) {
        spinner2List.clear();
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapterEmpty = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinner2List);
        adapterEmpty.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_layout);

        // Apply the adapter to the spinner
        spinner2.setAdapter(adapterEmpty);
    }
```

thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have called `spinner2List.clear();` but haven't notified the adapter by using **`notifyDataSetChanged();`** method.

Comment: clear() will call notifyDataSetChanged() unless setNotifyOnChange(false) had been called.

Answer (score 19):

when you select one of your first spinner Items you can use code below in first spinner onItemSelected() method to clear your second spinner.

```
 Spinner2.setAdapter(null)
```

Answer (score 3):

The Below Code is Used for Clearing the Spinner Value:-

```
ArrayList<String> allAreaNames;

                allAreaNames.clear();

                ArrayAdapter<String> AreaAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
                        (context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, allAreaNames);


                AreaAdapter.setDropDownViewResource
                        (android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

                AreaSpinner.setAdapter(AreaAdapter);
```

Comment: Appreciate your help :)