# How to clear choosen position in spinner?

Tags: android, position, spinner

Beacuse user can jump from positions in spinner;
I have something like that:

```
   public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
   switch ((int) parent.getSelectedItemId()){
            case 0:
                car = 1;
                motor = 0;
                break;
            case 1:
               // HERE I want clear case 0;
                bike = 1;
                motor = 0;
                // here car should be 0 again but the value is 1
                break;
            case 2:
               // HERE I want clear case 1 and case 0;
                bus = 1
                motor = 0;
                // here car and bike should be 0 again but the value is both 1
                break;
            default:
            motor = 1;
    }
}
```

In my opinion switch loop is good here.
How can I clear each separate case?
Also tried:
[Clear Spinner on Button press](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11703181/clear-spinner-on-button-press)
[how to clear spinner value in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14706497/how-to-clear-spinner-value-in-android)
[android spinner - how do I remove the current selection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16901271/android-spinner-how-do-i-remove-the-current-selection)
Maybe I should solve this problem otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spinners setSelection attribute to reset your Spinner to its original position.

```
spinner.setSelection(position);
```

by default value, you mean to say the value at 0 index. Then it should be

```
spinner.setSelection(0);
```